# What is the pop up/hoover box called in jquery/javascript/html/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I am at the beginning of researching how to do something and not sure what is the proper name of what I am trying to research and if there is something that can be done in jquery, or a mix of jquery and css. What I am looking for is something similar to a small pop up when you hover over something; similar to hovering over a hyperlink will reveal the full link. But it will be styled to something that looked like a dialog box and instead of hovering over it the user will have to click it to see that dialog box, but it will be displayed similar to hoovering over something. I hope this question is clear and that I am not over thinking this.

Comment: Maybe "tooltip"? Or "popover"?

Comment: @Ian tooltips. Gothca thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about tooltip? Check out this plugin called qTip 
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Comment: that what it is called. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with pure CSS if you wanted

DEMMO [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/LstNS/)

```
#talkbubble {
   width: 120px;
   height: 80px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
    margin-left:100px;
    padding:10px;
   -moz-border-radius:    10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius:         10px;
}
#talkbubble:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   right: 100%;
   top: 26px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 13px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid red;
   border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}
.alert {
  display: none;
}
span {
    display: line-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top:45px;
}

span:focus ~ .alert {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: You never fail to surprise me Vector!!

Answer (score 1):

I would 2nd SiDiX's recommendation of qTip if you are looking for a jQuery based solution. It has numerous features and is fairly easy to implement.

Since you mentioned you are still in the researching phase, I would suggest a google search on "[top jquery tooltip plugins](https://www.google.com/#fp=633e4ade33ba97d5&q=top+jquery+tooltip+plugins&safe=active)" - you will find many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking to define is referred to as a 'tooltip'. I like to use [PowerTip](http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/) to implement tooltips. It relies on jQuery, has lots of useful options, and outputs easily styled tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) and look at what they are calling Tooltip, popover, and modal. That should help clarify.

Comment: Funny you mention bootstrap, because I was looking at that the other day and did not know that they had that implemented already.

Answer (score 0):

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips...

tooltips and popovers by bootstrap...You can put in html in the tooltip if you want.